# Finding the minimum of an exponential function given its domain and maximum

Tags: exponential-function

The domain of function $y=a^{\vert(x-1)\vert+2}$ is $\{x\vert-1\le x\le2\}$, and the maximum value of the function (for the given domain) is $\frac 14$. The problem is the find the minimum value of the function using the given information.

I looked at the solution for this problem and it went like this:

First they take the exponent of the original function as f(x):
 $f(x)=\vert(x-1)\vert+2$

Using the given domain $\{x\vert-1\le x\le2\}$, it can be deduced that $-2\le x-1\le1$. I understood everything until here, but then it goes on to say that from this it can also be deduced that

$0\le \vert x-1\vert\le2$

I really don't get how this can be deduced...

Comment: Haha: A new problem for the CRUDE people and their disciples: Does regurgitating the full textbook solution count as enough "context" to save a question from the axe?

Answer (score 0):

Draw $y \mapsto |y|$. What's the image of $[-2; 1]$?